# Changing the color of <li> text to yellow in html

Tags: html-lists

I want to change the color of my li tag text into yellow. My background color is black and it seems that the default color in the li tag is black, so i want to change it to something bright like yellow or white. Please advice.

```
<h4>MA</h4>
<ul>

  <li>welcome to my city</li>
  <li>hello world.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a color via CSS, like li {color: yellow} or something?

Comment: How would i do that @alou ?

Comment: check my answer for an example

Answer (score 4):

Just to get you started, there are 2 ways of styling an html element:

- Inline styling
- Via css

You have to do some reading, as useSticks suggested but the quick and dirty way to get past through this is to do it by inline styling.

In any element, you can have a style attribute and have some values declared there. For example, in your case:

```
<ul>
  <li style="color:yellow">i am yellow</li>
  <li style="background:black;color:red;">I am red with black background</li>
</ul>
```

Play around and do some reading, css is quite a big chapter to discuss here.